# Iterate over first n files of file list

Tags: python, python-3.x

`file_list` is the folder path containing a list of files.

I want to do certain action on the files inside `file_list`. To perform the action on all the files, here is the python code;

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(file_list):
    print(filename)
```

What if I only want to perform the action on the first `n` files. How do I modify the code? I am open to totally new code to do the task.

I am using python v3.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(file_list)[:n]:
    print(filename)
```

Is it suitable for you?